# CSP header in not visible in network tab for third party resources

Tags: javascript, request-headers, response-headers, content-security-policy

I added a CSP header to my angular project. When I run it, csp-header in response header is only available for internal resources.
But for all other resouces like google maps , jquery cdn, font awesome it is not visible in network tab. I know that these resources are also abide by the CSP of my site. But clients want to see that  to be visible in network tab for their security audit purpose.

Is there anyway to show CSP header in the response headers of these 3rd party resource. Atleast a patch to manually add response header to these resource will work for me.

Comment: There's no way you could set response headers on the third-party servers.